# ByteString representation of a Double conversion

Tags: haskell, wav, data-conversion, bytestring

I'm writing my own `WAVE` parser that uses [Conduit](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/conduit-0.5.3/docs/Data-Conduit.html) so I can stream values, one by one, through a pipeline.

I get a sample from a .wav file via `hGet` (n is the number of bytes per sample for that wav file):

`bytes <- hGet h n`

This gives me a ByteString with a representation of the Double value of the sample. E.g.:

`"\131\237\242"` represents `-0.10212671756744385`

`"g\238\242"` represents `-0.10209953784942627`

`"\215\238\242"` represents `-0.10208618640899658`.

The possible values are between -1 and +1.

Is there any convenient way to do this conversion? Is there a library available to do this?

I've taken a look at existing `WAVE` parsers for Haskell. [Data.WAVE](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/WAVE-0.1.3/docs/Data-WAVE.html) parses a `.wav` file and returns the samples as left-justified `Int32` values. I've found a workaround where I use it's library functions to convert my `ByteString` to a left-justified `Int32` and then convert it to a `Double` using the library's `sampleToDouble` function. This works, but I'm wondering if there is a more direct way of solving this problem.

Another possible solution would be to convert the `ByteString` to `[Word8]` with `ByteString.unpack`, convert `[Word8]` to `Word32` and then convert this value to a `Float` using the conversion functions from [Data.Binary.IEEE754](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/data-binary-ieee754-0.4.4/docs/Data-Binary-IEEE754.html). Would this be a good solution? One problem is that I currently don't know how to convert a four-element list of [Word8] to Word32.

Comment: have you looked at `readDouble` in the `bytestring-lexing` library?

Comment: Those don't look like hex characters to me.

Comment: @liminalisht I have. But I can't seem to install the package. It looks like it has bitrotten...

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson You're right. I'm actually not quite sure what the representation is. I'll change the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my current solution to turn the ByteString into a double:

```
convertNBytesLen :: [Word8] -> Int32
convertNBytesLen = foldr accum 0
  where accum bs a = 256 * a + fromIntegral bs


bsToDouble :: S.ByteString -> Int -> Double
bsToDouble bs n = if intV >= 0
                   then fromIntegral intV / 2147483647
                   else - (fromIntegral intV / (-2147483648))
  where intV = convertNBytesLen (S.unpack bs) `shift` (32 - 8 * n)
```

I'm wondering if this can be done in a more efficient manner.