# Convert wav audio format ByteString to Floats

Tags: haskell, audio, wav, data-conversion

I'm working on sensor data that is stored in .wav files. The samples represent floating point numbers between -1 and 1.

I'm reading samples from the .wav file as `ByteString`s and I need a way to convert this `ByteString` to a `Float`. So I'm looking for a function with the following signature:

`toFloat :: ByteString -> Float`

For example. I'm working with a .wav file that contains 1 channel, has a framerate of 48kHz and samples consist of 24 bits. This means that each sample consists of 3 bytes and I can read it from the .wav file like this:
`hGet h 3`.
 Here, `h` is the handle of the .wav file.

How can I convert this ByteString I get from `hGet` to a `Float` (between -1 and 1)?

As you can see in my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41143884/bytestring-representation-of-a-double-conversion), I'm currently converting the `ByteString` to a `Double` by first converting it to an `Int32` (based on [Data.WAVE](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/WAVE-0.1.1/docs/Data-WAVE.html)). Since my samples are never bigger than 32 bits, I would like to use `Float`s instead of `Double`s. I'm also looking for a more efficient way of doing this conversion.

**EDIT**
I'm currently converting the `ByteString` first to an `Int32` and then to a `Double`. This is done by `bsToDouble`:

```
convertNBytesLen :: [Word8] -> Int32
convertNBytesLen = foldr accum 0
  where accum bs a = 256 * a + fromIntegral bs


bsToDouble :: S.ByteString -> Int -> Double
bsToDouble bs n = if intV >= 0
                   then fromIntegral intV / 2147483647
                   else - (fromIntegral intV / (-2147483648))
  where intV = convertNBytesLen (S.unpack bs) `shift` (32 - 8 * n)
```

The `ByteString` as input to `bsToDouble` comes straight from `hGet h 3` and the integer is the amount of bytes in a sample (which is 3).

Comment: How do you want to decode those 24 bits into a `Float`? You had mentioned `Data.Binary.IEEE754` in your previous question. In the source there is an example of decoding a 16 bit float, I would expect you need something similar for your 24 bits and then you can use `Data.Binary` to decode your stream.

Comment: Good luck with using that lib, it reads samples into a nested linked list. Last time I needed something like this I developed `wave`: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/wave. Without knowing your untimate goal it's hard to advise what is the best way to do what you want to do.

Comment: @Mark I'm not planning to use that lib. I've written my own library that streams the content of the .wav file using `Conduit`s. The only part I use from the library is the `ByteString` to `Double` conversion. But I'm looking for something more efficient.

Comment: @ryachza I don't know how I want to decode those 24 bits into a `Float`. That's my problem. I do not understand the example for 16 bits enough to make my own version for 24 bits.

Comment: @Mark Why is my ultimate goal important to solving this subproblem? I just need a way to convert my `ByteString`, I get from reading 3 bytes from the data chunk of the .wav file, to a `Float` (between -1 and 1). E.g. `hGet` gives me this `ByteString`: `"\131\237\242"`. It should be converted to a float containing `-0.10212671756744385`

Comment: Are you sure those samples in the file correspond to _floating point_, but within 24 bits? That would be a heck of a weird format. Normally, `.wav` files use fixed precision up to 24-bit, and floating point for 32-bit or 64-bit.

Comment: @leftaroundabout Yes, I'm sure.

Comment: Well, such a format is not included in the IEEE754 standard, nor do I think it's actually legal in a wav file. You'll need to manually sort out mantissa and exponent through bit twiddling.

Comment: @leftaroundabout Is that really necessary? I've added my current solution to my question. In that solution i'm just converting the `ByteString` to an `Int32` and then I'm converting the `Int32` to a `Double`. This works, but I want to get rid of the intermediate conversion to `Int32` and I would like a `Float` result instead of a `Double`. This conversion is based on the source code of `Data.WAVE` where samples are represented by `Int32`.

Comment: Well, fine, if that works it means that the samples are stored in 24-bit _integral_ format. Which makes sense too – 48kHz int24 is one of the most common audio formats.

Comment: @leftaroundabout Does that mean that there isn't a more efficient conversion than I'm currently using?

Comment: Well, you should most definitely avoid the intermediate list of `Word8`s. Use a serialisation library to get at the `Int24` values, then use `fromIntegral intV / 2^23` on these. I wouldn't scale the different signs differently – the only notable difference that would make is to introduce a little bit of distortion.

Comment: `wave` does not impose how you read and write contents of WAVE file, you can do it with conduits just as well, you can even do it in C. Why not use something existing and well-tested on build on top of that?

Comment: @leftaroundabout I've avoided having to `unpack` the `ByteString` by directly folding over the `ByteString` with `ByteString.foldr`. I've also used the same scale for each sign. This didn't result in a performance increase though. Can you point me to an example of using a serialisation library to get at the `Int24`'s values?

Comment: @Mark All I need is a list/array representation of the samples in my .wav file. From there, I've written all the functions to manipulate and extract the required information. The data in the .wav files is not really "audio", it is a artificially created signal that represents the "state" of an engine in time. Values range from -1 to 1 and I just need to analyze a list of them. What would you recommend that is existing and well-tested?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does something like this help:

```
import Data.Int (Int32)
import Data.Bits ((.|.),(.&.),unsafeShiftL)
import Data.Word (Word32)
import Data.Binary
import qualified Data.ByteString as BS
import qualified Data.ByteString.Unsafe as BSU

int32_24be :: BS.ByteString -> Int32
int32_24be = \s ->
  let x =   unsafeShiftL (fromIntegral (BSU.unsafeIndex s 0)) 16
        .|. unsafeShiftL (fromIntegral (BSU.unsafeIndex s 1))  8
        .|.               fromIntegral (BSU.unsafeIndex s 2)
        :: Int32
      y = fromIntegral x :: Word32
  in fromIntegral (if x .&. 0x00800000 > 0 then y .|. 0xFF000000 else y .&. 0x00FFFFFF)

getFloat :: BS.ByteString -> Float
getFloat = (/ 2^^23) . fromIntegral . int32_24be
```

My thought is that the 24 bit values are integers, and you want to normalize them to a float between -1 and 1 (positive 1 excluded, though). If this is the case, I'm thinking you would be able to use `getFloat` with `Data.Binary.Get` to parse your stream 24 bits at a time.

Comment: This could definitely help! Though, it doesn't give me the correct result. I've been looking at the source code of the WAVE parser that works for my .wav files (Data.WAVE) and it says in the module description: `This module currently supports reading and writing single-section little-endian PCM audio files containing up to 32-bit samples encoded according to the well-known WAVE sample encoding.'. So I think the problem is that your conversion uses big-endian. I think you're right about the values being 24 bit integers that have to be normalized. I will take a look at the `Get` monad. Thank you

Comment: @ThomasVanhelden Yeah it's definitely a matter of inverting whatever the original encoding is. If it was little-endian, I think you would just need to reverse the indices (2,1,0 instead of 0,1,2).

Comment: Reversing the indices (0,1,2 to 2,1,0) did the trick. The performance is better than my current implementation. Thank you!

Comment: By the way, removing the redundant lambda expression seems to do even better.

Comment: @ThomasVanhelden Are you referring to the `\s ->` versus `int32_24be s =`? The difference is related to inlining as I believe GHC will only inline fully applied functions. So the performance may vary based on optimizations and exact use.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this to convert to `Double`, it seems it could help with floats too - it assumes the binary representation of the underlying number is the same as the in-memory representation.:
https://hackage.haskell.org/package/reinterpret-cast

```
wordToFloat :: Word32 -> Float
```

It seems however that the 24-bit in WAV would have different memory characteristics than your underlying platform - if you find the correct mantissa/exponent lengths, it should be quite easy to convert it to proper 32-bit float and use this function to do the conversion.